# Formulário em Django para key única

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Boa tarde pessoal.

Eu tenho um modelo em Django com um campo - phone - que é uma chave única:

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
```

Estou tentando gerar um formulário no qual o usuário entra no site e coloca o telefone, mas estou recebendo erro dizendo que o telefone já está na base. O meu objetivo é justamente que o telefone esteja na base.

form.py

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('phone', )
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" class="client-form">
    {% csrf_token %}    
    {{ form.phone }}    
    <button type="submit" class="save btn">CONTINUAR</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def get_phone(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            client = Client.objects.filter(phone=phone).first()
```

O problema é que ele não passa do `form.is_valid()`.
O que eu tenho que fazer de diferente para ele entender que quero fazer uma consulta de um número que já existe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi completamente o seu contexto, mas parece que vc ja tem os telefones gravados no banco e quer que o usuario digite o telefone como se fosse uma credencial para entrada em alguma parte do sistema, é isso? Se for isso voce esta usando o verbo `http` errado, na verdade nem esta diretamente relacionado ao django e sim ao desenvolvimento web, tente trocar o métdo `post` pelo método `get`

```
<form method="GET" class="client-form">
    {% csrf_token %}    
    {{ form.phone }}    
    <button type="submit" class="save btn">CONTINUAR</button>
</form>
```

Claro que vc vai ter que alterar a view também.

O ideal seria fazer todo o tutorial da documentação, se quiser ver diretamente o topico de formularios aponte para https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/intro/tutorial04/